# docker won't start! I'm stuck on "Docker Desktop stopped

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-desktop

I've tried installing Docker and so far I've never been able to use it on my Ubuntu machine:
when I try to start Docker Desktop it only shows Docker Desktop stopped... for an indefinite amount of time. There sometimes shows up randomly an Alert with the messages "Unable to calculate image disk size" for a second or so,[image: Docker Alert] but it doesn't really help me at all. I'm also not Using Docker very often so I have only a little experience with it.

At this point Docker is always the first program that shows up automatically when I boot up my computer. and it instantly goes to the message: "Docker Desktop stopped..." when I click on the bug Icon I already tried the oprions "Restart", "Clean/Purge data" and "Reset to factory defaults" but none of those options helped me so far. I also can't access the Settings page it only shows a loading animation when I try to open it.

Comment: I'm not clear there's a good reason to use Docker Desktop on a native-Linux host; you should be able to install the core Docker engine using APT.  If this is just a question about installing Docker, another site like [ubuntu.se] or [unix.se] might be a more appropriate place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The only solution I found is to reinstall docker every time I log in. It seems to work fine until I restart the computer.
It is a very bad solution but it's the best that I've got so far.